# Как сделать, чтобы цикл в консоли отображался одной строкой?

Tags: javascript

```js
var number = prompt("введите цифру");
var str = "";
var star = "*"

for(var a = 0; a < number; a++)
{
  str += star;
  console.log(str);
}
```

Comment: Escape последовательностями, курсор в строке надо двигать назад, или использовать метод  `Console.SetCursorPosition(..,..)` если об этом этот туманный вопрос..

Comment: @NewView судя по prompt дело происходит в браузере

Comment: Точно! в браузере, и это JavaScript :) я с разбегу не рассмотрел, на `C#` похоже, `console.log` не углядел.. :)

Comment: Кажется, никак. Браузерная консоль не предназначена для прогрессбаров.

Comment: Да ладно. Если никак - придётся придумать)

Comment: *Как сделать, чтобы цикл в консоли отображался одной строкой?* - выводить цикл одной строкой т.е. вызвать console.log один раз по окончанию цикла.

Answer (score 1):

Если я вас правильно понял, то вот так:

```js
var number = prompt("введите цифру");
var str = "";
var star = "*"

for(var a = 0; a < number; a++)
{
  str += star;
}

console.log(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно вот так попробовать:

```js
{
  const orig = console.log.bind(console);
  let all = [];
  console.log = (...args) => {
    all = all.concat(args);
    console.clear();
    orig(...all);
  };
  console._restoreLog = () => console.log = orig;
}

for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  console.log(i, '* 2 =', {res: 2*i});
}

console._restoreLog();

console.log('Важно восстанавливать нормальное поведение');
```

*Лучше смотреть в настоящей консоли. Единственный артефакт - сообщение об очистке консоли(вкупе с самой очисткой всего, что было до нас)*